User is not authorized to perform: bedrock:CreateKnowledgeBase
I am trying to create a bedrock knowledgebase using aws sdk. but when i try to hit the createKnowledgeBase method if gives me the below error.
User: arn:aws:iam::85172538xxxx:user/bedrock_assist_user is not authorized to perform: bedrock:CreateKnowledgeBase

I even tried giving the bedrock:CreateKnowledgeBase in policy to the user
and it still gives the same error, i even gave AdministratorAccess, but still same error.
Any pointers on what can be happening wrong?
Below is my java code
VectorKnowledgeBaseConfiguration vkbc = VectorKnowledgeBaseConfiguration.builder()
                .embeddingModelArn(embeddingModelArn)
                .build();
        KnowledgeBaseConfiguration kbc = KnowledgeBaseConfiguration.builder()
                .vectorKnowledgeBaseConfiguration(vkbc)
                .build();

        OpenSearchServerlessConfiguration sssc = OpenSearchServerlessConfiguration.builder()
                .collectionArn(collectionArn)
                .vectorIndexName("bedrock-knowledge-base-default-index")
                .fieldMapping(builder -> builder
                                .metadataField("AMAZON_BEDROCK_METADATA")
                                .textField("AMAZON_BEDROCK_TEXT_CHUNK")
                                .vectorField("bedrock-knowledge-base-default-vector")
                                .build()
                )
                .build();
        StorageConfiguration sc = StorageConfiguration.builder()
                .opensearchServerlessConfiguration(sssc)
                .build();
        CreateKnowledgeBaseRequest req = CreateKnowledgeBaseRequest.builder()
                .knowledgeBaseConfiguration(kbc)
                .storageConfiguration(sc)
                .roleArn(kbServiceRole)
                .name(knowledgeBaseName)
                .description("Knowledge Base ")
                .build();
        CreateKnowledgeBaseResponse res =  bedrockAgentClient.createKnowledgeBase(req);


Is your account part of an organization?, If so there might be a service control policy (SCP) denying such action

Thanks @AleSosa I think this might be the case. Is there any way I can check the SCP on my end? Or maybe check the effective  permissions of an iam user

You likely cannot verify this yourself, beyond the fact that your API request fails. Talk to your org admin.

Hi @jarmod Thanks for your insight, i still have a doubt, when i login (using sso in identity center implied by the organization) i can perform this action, but the user i created in IAM couldn't. Is it still the effect of SCP, like it only applies to IAM user not the ones in identity center?

Apparently on extensive debugging through cloudtrail I found out that I was missing a parameter in payload to the request. As you can see I am missing a type field in storage configuration. Surprisingly I don't know why it is leading to a Unauthorised error when it should give a bad request or validation error.
Thanks everyone for helping me out!!
